# Multiple if Statements within a function in an Object?

Tags: php, class, object, if-statement

Hi i need to check if an Object can have 0 or 1 for two parameters which are R1 and R2 - it's like directions from Obj A to Obj B - Where 1 means Obj A can access Obj B and 0 means Obj A cannot access Obj B. My if statements work until the first true statement. How to make them check both R1 and R2 directions

```
<?php

class MyObject {

    function directionsRn($R1, $R2, $objSource, $objDest) {


        if ($R1 == 1) {

            echo("$objSource can access $objDest via R1 <br>");

            } else if ($R1 == 0) {

                       echo("SORRY, but $objSource CANNOT access $objDest via R1 <br>");

                       } else if ($R2 == 1) {

                                  echo("$objSource can access $objDest via R12<br>");

                                  }  else if ($R2 == 0) {

                                              echo("SORRY, but $objSource CANNOT access $objDest via R1 <br>");

                                              } 

    }           

}

$myObject_array[0] = new MyObject();

$myObject_array[0]->directionsRn(0, 0, 'A', 'B');

print_r($myObject_array);



?>
```

Comment: You should indent your code in a logical manner; indentation suggests that the `elseif` statements are "inside" the `if` statements, which they are not.

Comment: @miken32 if you actually think about, it is _properly_* indented. `else..if` != `elseif`. Note that I agree with you. Indentation is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it by changing from

```
} else if ($R2 == 1) {
```

to

```
}

if ($R2 == 1) {
```

---

If you properly ident your code, it would look like this:

```
if ($R1 == 1) {
    echo("$objSource can access $objDest via R1 <br>");
} else if ($R1 == 0) {
    echo("SORRY, but $objSource CANNOT access $objDest via R1 <br>");
} else if ($R2 == 1) {
    echo("$objSource can access $objDest via R12<br>");
} else if ($R2 == 0) {
    echo("SORRY, but $objSource CANNOT access $objDest via R1 <br>");
}
```

Can you see that it's all part of one `if`?

---

They'd look like this separated (note that I changed to elseif too):

```
if ($R1 == 1) {
    echo("$objSource can access $objDest via R1 <br>");
} elseif ($R1 == 0) {
    echo("SORRY, but $objSource CANNOT access $objDest via R1 <br>");
}

if ($R2 == 1) {
    echo("$objSource can access $objDest via R12<br>");
} elseif ($R2 == 0) {
    echo("SORRY, but $objSource CANNOT access $objDest via R1 <br>");
}
```

Comment: so we can nest else if statements this way ?

Comment: also, a quick question @FirstOne is there a way to write a function that will be checking if an Object let's say object A has access to Object D, there are also Object C and Object B and the only way to connect from A to D is is A has at least R1 or R2 access to B and B has R1 or R2 access to C and C has R1 or R2 access to D

Comment: It would be better if you just use [elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: @ThePickyGuy now if you check the links from [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and think that your follow up question is fit for SO, then create a new question, please ;)

Comment: got it. I will create a new question

Comment: Thank you for you commitment